# Разработка шаблона для "обертки" статически типизированного API для использования с динамическими объектами

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне приходится работать с динамически-типизированными объектами:

```
struct DynamicObject { /* реализация */ };
```

Для распаковки/упаковки статических типов служит семейство конвертеров, которые представляют собой специализации общего шаблона для конкретных типов:

```
template<typename T>
struct DynamicObjectConverter {
    static inline T unpack(DynamicObject) { return T(); };
    static inline DynamicObject pack(T) { return DynamicObject(); };
};
```

API приложения представляет собой набор статических методов с самыми разными сигнатурами (т.е. все они принимают различное количество аргументов различных типов и возвращают значения различных типов). Например:

```
struct Application {
    static inline long function(char arg1, int arg2) { return 42; };
};
```

Для каждой такой функции мне приходится писать обертки для работы с объектами DynamicObject. Например, для вышеприведенной Application::function это выглядит так:

```
DynamicObject wrapped_function(DynamicObject arg_1_object, DynamicObject arg_2_object) {
    auto arg_1 = DynamicObjectConverter<char>::unpack(arg_1_object);
    auto arg_2 = DynamicObjectConverter<int>::unpack(arg_2_object);
    auto result = Application::function(arg_1, arg_2);
    return DynamicObjectConverter<long>::pack(result);
}
```

За счет того, что все статические методы DynamicObjectConverter::unpack, DynamicObjectConverter::pack и Application::function являются встраиваемыми, компилятор генерирует одну монолитную функцию, принимающую/возвращающую DynamicObject, которая избавлена от промежуточных вызовов и очень сильно оптимизирована внутри.

Но я считаю, что подобные обертки должны генерироваться автоматически с использованием шаблона:

```
int test() {
    auto arg_1 = DynamicObject();
    auto arg_2 = DynamicObject();
    // Вместо этого:
    DynamicObject result = wrapped_function(arg_1, arg_2);
    // Я хочу писать так:
    DynamicObject result = wrapped<Application::function>(arg_1, arg_2);
};
```

Проблема в том, что если параметром шаблона является статический метод, то внутри шаблона я не могу получить типы возвращаемого значения и аргументов, количество которых также может быть различно. Такой вариант шаблонна, конечно, не скомпилируется:

```
template <typename F>
DynamicObject wrapped(std::initializer_list<DynamicObject> objects) {
    // как во время компиляции гарантировать количество аргументов ? 
    auto objects_iter = objects.begin();
    // как из F получить Arg1Type, Arg2Type и типы остальных аргументов ?
    auto arg_1 = DynamicObjectConverter<Arg1Type>::unpack(*(objects_iter++));
    auto arg_2 = DynamicObjectConverter<Arg2Type>::unpack(*objects_iter);
    // как обобщить это на случай другого количества аргументов ? 
    auto result = F(arg_1, arg_2);
    // как из F получить ResultType
    return DynamicObjectConverter<ResultType>::pack(result);
}
```

Возможна ли вообще реализация простого в пользовании шаблонна такой "обертки"? Или это выходит за рамки возможностей языка?

**Update:**

Уточню, что конечной целью является экспортирование API, состоящего из обернутых функций, принимающих/возвращающих динамические объекты так, чтобы в них оказались **встроены** тела оригинальных оборачиваемых функций, работающих со статическими типами. При том, что API состоит из большого количества мелких функций с различными сигнатурами, очень важно, чтобы их оборачивание и экспортирование осуществлялось наиболее удобным образом, по возможности с минимальным дублированием кода, без необходимости вручную указывать типы, которые можно вывести из сигнатур функций.

**Update 2:**

Некоторый прогресс в решении: http://cpp.sh/2gsa - то, чего я достиг на данный момент. Это демонстрирует принципиальную возможность использования шаблонов, для генерации оберток, удовлетворяющих условиям задачи. Остается один недостаток в необходимости указания принимаемых/возвращаемых типов для оборачиваемой функции при инстанциации такого шаблона:

```
    wrapped<long, char, int>::function<Application::test>
```

Остается найти возможность вывода этих типов (и их количества) из сигнатуры оборачиваемой функции.

Comment: Ну я бы попробовал перегрузить десяток вариантов функции wrapped для разного количества аргументов. [Как-то так](http://cpp.sh/7cf4a). Предлагаю такой вариант потому что не смог придумать как вызвать функцию unpack к каждому аргументу функции обертки, если обобщить wrapped при помощи variadic templates.

Comment: Если отказаться от идеи с функцией оберткой, то проблему может решить добавление в DynamicObject шаблонного конструктора и operator T. [Решение](http://cpp.sh/4hwh), на мой взгляд, получается более универсальное и короткое.

Comment: @yrhetatejlb : Концентрируя работу со всеми (?) статическими типами внутри класса DynamicObject я теряю гибкость решения и возможно впоследствии расширять набор статических типов, для которых определены преобразования. Насколько я понимаю устройство стандартной библиотеки - там подобные проблемы принято решать введением type traits, у меня эту роль играет DynamicObjectConverter.

Comment: ну можно написать шаблонную обертку для DynamicObject. У которой будет необходимый конструктор и оператор приведения типа. Шаблонный параметром будет конвертер. Не знаю что у вас там в проекте происходит, но рекомендую не переусложнять. Можно хоть до бесконечности писать фабрики, адаптеры и обертки. И в итоге получить [это](https://gist.github.com/lolzballs/2152bc0f31ee0286b722)

Comment: @yrhetatejlb : В вашем первом варианте не происходит **компиляции** обертки вместе с оборачиваемой функцией. Вместо этого происходит **динамическая** (во время исполнения) передача в обертку **указателя** на функцию. Я в своем коде специально использую статические методы классов вместо независимых функций, чтобы в шаблонах избегать передачи функции по указателю, и заставить компилятор **встраивать** в шаблон сами **тела** функций, а это возможно только при использовании, определенных в том месте, методов классов.

Comment: ну тогда смотрите в сторону [препроцессора](http://cpp.sh/5tg3t). Потому что метод Application вы никак не передадите в качестве параметра кроме как через [указатель или ссылку](http://cpp.sh/6vcjy).

Comment: Но имейте ввиду поголовное встраивание функций, использование шаблонов и препроцессора приводит к раздуванию кода.

Answer (score 4):

Всё довольно просто:

```
template<typename R, typename... A, typename... P>
DynamicObject wrapped(R(*f)(A...), P&&... p) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(A) == sizeof...(P), "");
    auto&& result = f(DynamicObjectConverter<A>::unpack(p)...);
    return DynamicObjectConverter<R>::pack(std::move(result));
}

// Вызов:
DynamicObject result = wrapped(&Application::function, arg_1, arg_2);
```

Типы аргументов и возвращаемого значения выводятся в `R(*f)(A...)`.

`static_assert(sizeof...(A) == sizeof...(P), "");` не обязателен, но позволяет получить более красивое сообщение об ошибке.

Выражение `f(DOC<A>::unpack(p)...)` преобразует переданные параметры в нужные типы и вызывает функцию.

`auto&& result = f();` не работает если функция возвращает `void`. Для этого случая надо писать отдельную специализацию.

`f` должна быть аргументом `wrapped`, а не параметром шаблона. Потому что иначе придется писать

```
template<typename R, typename... A, R(*f)(A...), typename... P>
DynamicObject wrapped(P&&... p);
// Вызов:
wrapped<decltype(f), f>(arg1, arg2);
```

(В С++17 это починят, можно будет писать `template<auto f>`)

Comment: Если оборачиваемая функция передается в обертку по ссылке, то, во-первых, не получится встраивания тела этой функции в обертку, что позволило бы компилятору (при тривиальной логике распаковщиков/упаковщиков) провести мощную оптимизацию и исключить двойную передачу аргументов в обертку и в оборачиваемую функцию.
Во-вторых, чтобы экспортировать API, представляющее собой обернутые функции, требуется дополнительно писать (копировать схожий код) для каждой такой функции, что почти эквивалентно написанию (копированию) схожих друг с другом оберток без использования шаблонов.

Comment: @cridnirk Офтоп конечно и не мое дело, но я бы вам порекомендовал не зацикливаться так на встравании. Во-первых вы не можете явно заставить комплятор встраивать функции, во-вторых встраивание эффективно когда контекст вызова более насыщен т.к. у компилятора появляется больше возможностей чтобы поиграть в оптимизацию, сособенно в циклах. Поэтому эти усилия не стоят копеешного выигрыша который вы скорее всего получите. Порофилировщик ответит на вопрос стоит ли этим заниматься.

Comment: Во-первых, я всегда контролирую генерируемый компилятором код (ассемблерный листинг) когда меня интересует производительность и всегда ориентируюсь на тот код, который желаю получить на выходе. Я бы не использовал высокоуровневые абстракции и ООП вообще, если бы не был уверен, что компилятор все это выкинет без следа и сгенерериет код, аналогичный тому, что я мог бы написать на чистом C. Я использую C++ потому, что это единственный из распространенных ЯВУ, который благодаря механизму шаблонов способен генерировать желаемый код (а не кучу функций), не принося в жертву высокоуровневые абстракции

Comment: @Cerbo: (прошлый комментарий тоже вам). Во-вторых, конкретно в данном случае встраивание крайне эффективно потому, что кроме собственно удаления вызовов (call), удаляется еще весь код, отвечающий за передачу параметров, а в случае тривиальных распаковщиков/упаковщиков (проверка поля, определяющего тип и возврат значения из другого поля) и простой логики оборачиваемых функций, такой код может составлять большую часть объема и влиять на производительность в разы. Без этой оптимизации отделение кода распаковщиков/упаковщиков не было бы оправданно несмотря на все удобство и красоту такого подхода.

Comment: @Abyx: Посоветуйте пожалуйста такой язык (общего назначения или DSL), который бы генерировал код так, как это позволяют шаблоны C++. Решаемая мной проблема пришла как раз из практики: C++ как инструмент был выбран после того как были перепробованы все более простые подходы. Это уже третья (или четвертая) реализации моей библиотеки для Python. Предыдущие были на основе Cython и Numba (numba.pydata.org) - в целом это эффективные инструменты, но не позволяющие сочетать высокоуровневые концепции с требуемым уровнем производительности и заставляющие выбирать одно из двух.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю просто добавить шаблонный конструктор и оператор приведения в `DynamicObject`:

```
class DynamicObject
{
// ...
    template<typename T>
    DynamicObject(T arg)
    {
        *this = DynamicObjectConverter<T>::pack(arg);
    }

    template<typename T>
    operator T () const
    {
        return DynamicObjectConverter<T>::unpack(*this);
    }

// ...
};
```

В результате никаких обверток вам не понадобится, можно будет функции библиотеки использовать напрямую:

```
auto arg1 = DynamicObject(10);
auto arg2 = DynamicObject(20);
DynamicObject result = Application::function(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Я ему уже это предлагал. И даже код у меня с вами один в один. Но автора чем-то такое решение не устроило. Можете посмотреть обсуждение

Comment: Я уточнил (обновил) вопрос с учетом того, что мое API состоит из десятков **не обернутых** функций (работающих с конкретными статическими типами и имеющих разные сигнатуры), мне требуется экспортировать API, состоящие из **обернутых** функций (работающих с динамическими объектами условно одного типа). Как ваше решение (возможно, дополненное) поможет это реализовать без массового дублирования кода?

Comment: @cridnirk То есть вы хотите чтобы исходный АПИ был полностью скрыт

Comment: Цель - Экспорт API, состоящего из **обернутых** функций, которые генерируются из не обернутых. Я не хочу модифицировать исходное API, чтобы заставить все функции работать с динамическими объектами, так как это размажет реализацию распаковщиков/упаковщиков по всему коду, вызовет дублирование кода и закроет дальнейшую возможность изменения/расширения реализации распаковщиков/упаковщиков отдельно от остального кода. Поэтому логика разделена на распаковщики/упаковщики, отвечающие за подготовку аргументов и возвращаемых значений и, внутренне API, независимое от динамической природы внешней среды.

Answer (score 0):

К тому что вы уже написали добавьте это:

```
template<class R, class ...Args>
constexpr wrapped<R, Args...> makeWrapped(R(Args...)){
    return wrapped<R, Args...>();
}
#define WRAPPED(func) makeWrapped(func).function<func>
```

и пишите

```
static constexpr DynamicFunction DynamicAPI[] = {
    WRAPPED(Application::test)
}
```

http://cpp.sh/4hri